# Using shutil.copyfile() to copy shapefiles from one folder to another using a text list

Tags: python, shapefile

I am trying to copy shapefiles from one folder to another using a list of shapefile names saved in a txt file (shapefile name: BH_0231). I have the script below that works for copying one file type, but I can not figure out how to use it to copy all the associated files with a shapefile (.shp, .dbf, .prj etc.). I am wondering if I need to use the `glob.glob()` function, but I am not sure how.

```
# Script reads a list Contour names from a text file,
# verifies the tile exists,
# then copies the tile to a given location

import os
import shutil
import glob

# text file containing a single field of tile names
inpfile = open('C:\\Users\\natha\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\ContourSelectionProject\\ContourTiles.txt','r')

# index variable for line numbers (just for knowing how many tiles have been copied so far)
i = 1
for text_line in inpfile.readlines():
    # define file name
    filename = text_line[0:7]
    # define path to the contour tiles
    path = 'C:\\Users\\natha\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\ContourSelectionProject\\Contours\\' + filename
    if os.path.exists(path):
        new_path = 'C:\\Users\\natha\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\ContourSelectionProject\\Contours' + filename
        shutil.copyfile(path,new_path)
        print(str(i) + ' copied ' + filename)
        i += 1
    else:
        print( str(i) + path + ' MISSING')
        i += 1
inpfile.close()
```

Comment: I think this is a pure Python question that would be better researched at [so].  There is nothing special about you wanting to use it on shapefiles.  The code you are trying to write is for copying all files with the same root name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import shutil
import glob


inpfile = open('c:\\source_folder\\shapefile_names.txt','r') 

for text_line in inpfile.readlines():
    # define source file pattern -> c:\source_folder\BH_0231
    path = 'c:\\source_folder\\' + text_line[0:7] 
    
    # get files which have the same name
    for f in glob.glob(path + '.*'):  # c:\source_folder\BH_0231.*
        # construct the target file path.
        # f[-4:] gets the extension -> .shp/.prj etc.
        new_path = 'c:\\target_folder\\'  + filename + f[-4:] 
        shutil.copyfile(f, new_path)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This script worked perfectly after I defined the filename (filename = text_line[0:7]).